# Cannot change vbox border on #vbox:focused

Tags: java, css, javafx, focus, vbox

When vboxs are focased can we use css to change them?

```
#vbox{
   -fx-border-radius:8;
   -fx-border-width:2;
   -fx-border-color: #333333;

   }

//this works
#myvbox:hover {
   -fx-border-color: #455A64;

   }

//this does not
#myvbox:focused{
   -fx-border-color: #000000;

   }
```

Hover works fine. But trying to set color of focused vbox it does not work.

Comment: The border won't be visible if it has no width (default is 0, AFAIK).

Comment: @sillyfly i did not add the base code of the vbox added now.

Comment: This is not CSS what you have here.

Comment: Does the VBox have a border when not focused and not hovered? In your example you have `#vbox` but `#myvbox:focused`

Comment: Is the `VBox` actually focused? Usually `Pane`s themselves are not focused...

Comment: @sillyfly yes vbox has border when not hovered and hovered, but with the nex hex value. and when not focused.

Comment: VBox is a layout not a control !

Comment: It could be helpful to describe, how exactly the `VBox` gets the focus and clarifying, if it's the `VBox` itself that needs to have the focus or if you want to style the `VBox`, if ***it contains a descendant that has the focus***.